# How do I view the timeline of events that happened on a post?

Tags: support, user-interface

What do I do to see the timeline of events that happened on a question or an answer?  The events include votes, comments, revisions, closures, deletions, reopens, and undeletes.

Comment: This seems to have been first announced at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36303/177408

Comment: The method described below also works to get to the "revisions" of a question. Often there is no need for this, as once there was an edit there is a link in the middle of the post, but if there were closure-reopens or tag-only edits it can be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the post's id number.  If you're interested in a question you are viewing, then the post's id number is the number after the text `/questions/` in the URL.  If you're interested in an answer, then click on the link `share` at the bottom left of the answer then look at the URL that appears.  The post id number of the answer is the number after the text `/a/`.

Then, enter the URL: `https://{site}.stackexchange.com/posts/{id}/timeline`, where `{site}` depends on the site and `{id}` is the post's id number.

For example, the URL for the question above is
https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/572/timeline
and the URL for this answer is https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/573/timeline.

Comment: This technique doesn't seem to work if the post has been deleted and you don't have enough reputation to view deleted posts.

Answer (score 1):

there's an app for this. i used to have it on chrome a few weeks to moths ago but uninstalled it.

i think one of these:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-timeline/omclkfdjappannhpjjngnnppfmidlbbh?hl=en

https://stackapps.com/questions/4148/view-post-timeline

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sidebaroverflow/lhieihmjhlbhpjkamdjfjldcapnmhddp?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for this.  I don't use Chrome, so I wasn't able to test your first and third link.  But the second link seems useful.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche LOL

Answer (score 1):

The timeline for any post can now be accessed by clicking on the clock icon next to the post under the vote buttons.

Relevant [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) post: [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447#342316)